# how to dynamically change global stylesheets in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have two CSS files one for Light theme and other for Dark theme.
How to dynamically change the style sheets ?

### Here is the code i am currently using in __app.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import "primereact/resources/primereact.min.css";
import "primeicons/primeicons.css";
import { ThemeContext } from "../context/ThemeContext";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (theme == "dark") {
      import("primereact/resources/themes/arya-blue/theme.css");
    }
    if (theme == "light") {
      import("primereact/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css");
    }
  }, [theme]);

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={[theme, setTheme]}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

This code is working to switch from light theme to dark theme but it fails to switch from dark to light. Is their any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem by this [blog post](https://pulkitgoyal.in/conditional-global-stylesheets-for-nextjs-apps) with some differences.

##### 1. Created a new Themes.js file which contains both dark mode and light mode styles

---

```
const DarkTheme = () => {
  return (
    <style jsx global>
      {`
       Copied here the entire dark mode style sheet from node modules (around 5000 lines)
      `}
    </style>
  );
};

const LightTheme = () => {
  return (
    <style jsx global>
      {`
       Copied here the entire light mode style sheet from node modules (around 5000 lines)
      `}
    </style>
  );
};

export default function Theme({ theme }) {
  if (theme == "dark") {
    return <DarkTheme />;
  }
  return <LightTheme />;
}
```

##### 2. Used the Themes component inside __App.js file with context and theme persistence with local storage:

---

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import "primereact/resources/primereact.min.css";
import "primeicons/primeicons.css";
import { ThemeContext } from "../context/ThemeContext";
import Theme from "../themes/Theme"; //imported newly created theme file
import PrimeReact from "primereact/api";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState((typeof window !== "undefined" && localStorage.getItem("theme")) || "light");

  useEffect(() => {
    typeof window !== "undefined" && localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
  }, [theme]);

  return (
    <>
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={[theme, setTheme]}>
        <Theme theme={theme} /> {//This Component provides dynamic global styles}
          <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when switching back to `light` theme from `dark` theme your app contains the css of both `dark` and `light` themes.

One solution that comes to my mind is to store the theme state in local storage and then reload the page , something like this

Although it has a drawback that upon theme change your website would lose all the other states

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import "primereact/resources/primereact.min.css";
import "primeicons/primeicons.css";
import { ThemeContext } from "../context/ThemeContext";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");
  const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("theme",theme)
    window.location.reload();
  }, [theme]);

  if (currentTheme == "dark") {
      import("primereact/resources/themes/arya-blue/theme.css");
    }
    if (currentTheme == "light") {
      import("primereact/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css");
    }

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={[theme, setTheme]}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: The explanation is correct, but this won't work. You need to set `currentTheme` (hence the imports too) inside (another) `useEffect`. `localStorage` is not defined on server.  +1 anyways! -- Also, declare `currentTheme` like this instead: `localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'light'` as for the user visiting the site for first time, the theme will not be set. As an alternative you could change two `if`s to an `if`-`else` block too.

Comment: Thanks for answering :) Yes there are two stylesheets that are inline as you said. Both are injected as inline styles by nextjs with one recently imported with higher precedence. I thought the same to set a local storage but the problem is the application I am building relays a lot on present state. And by refresh all data will be lost which can be prevented by setting local storage items but there are so many elements to preserve state for dark mode :(